# Generate Bitcoin public addresses with balances from list of private keys

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script which will take as input the file containing a list of Bitcoin private keys and generate the public address for that key(s), check final balance, total received and the total sent as output, using blockchain info.

This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from pybitcoin import BitcoinPrivateKey

keys = set()
with open('private_keys.txt'):
    for priv in keys:
        try:
            p = BitcoinPrivateKey(priv)
            pub = p.public_key().address()
            r = requests.get("https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/{}".format(pub))
            time.sleep(1)
            print '{} {} {:20} {:20} {:20} ".format(priv, pub, r.json()['final_balance'], r.json()['total_received'], r.json()['total_sent'])'
        except (AssertionError, IndexError):
            pass
        except ValueError:
            print r
            print r.text
```

Now, when I try to run this, I get:

```
File "btc.py", line 12
    print '{} {} {:20} {:20} {:20} ".format(priv, pub, r.json()['final_balance'], r.json()['total_received'], r.json()['total_sent'])'
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I assume the solution to this problem is probably the simple one, but this keeps driving me crazy as I cannot understand why it is not working.

Comment: The format strings begins with a single quotation mark and ends with a double one.

Comment: Stupid me, probably my full-time job took its toll on my brain.
No syntax errors are appearing anymore, but parsing the output doesn't work, now to a new challenge.

Thanks for stating the obvious